# Why does my go binary change each time I rebuild?

Tags: go

Why does rerunning `go build ./` on some projects yield different results each time?

For example:

```
$ cd go/src/github.com/google/cadvisor
$ go build ./
$ sh1sum cadvisor
cdfc3c38898e2decd5df35b661737f7cc4f514ed  cadvisor
$ go build ./
$ sha1sum cadvisor
a94db96d684225e7a45cc68c5341fe6f57897c23  cadvisor
```

Full isolated setup:

```
$ go version
go version go1.6.2 linux/amd64
$ export GOPATH=$(mktemp -d)
$ cd $GOPATH
$ go get github.com/tools/godep
$ go get github.com/google/cadvisor
package github.com/influxdb/influxdb/client: code in directory /tmp/tmp.2MxFdNmdDe/src/github.com/influxdb/influxdb/client expects import "github.com/influxdata/influxdb/client"
$ cd src/github.com/google/cadvisor
$ $GOPATH/bin/godep restore
godep: WARNING: Go version (go1.6) & $GO15VENDOREXPERIMENT= wants to enable the vendor experiment, but disabling because a Godep workspace (Godeps/_workspace) exists
$ go build ./
...
```

Comment: Never used Go, but I suspect that the behavior is intentional. I've already worked in a place, where each time we would get a compiled Win32 MFC application, the binary was made to be intentionally different. The reason was to free us from responsibility and liability when  the costumer requested the source-code, in the possible case of it being touched. Normally it would not happen, as the customer's main reason to want the source was not to maintain it, but to have it in the case of our bankruptcy, the software producers

Comment: If go was intentionally adding variation to the builds, I would expect it to always change. That is not the case though, as a small "hello world" style program will produce identical binaries when recompiled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're using CGO, Go creates a tmp directory that gets used to compile the C code and the path gets embedded in the binary.

<strike>There was an issue about it but I can't find it now.</strike>

Issues [9206](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/9206) and [13247](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/13247).

Answer (score 0):

1- This is sample code which changes itself every time you build it (also because of embedded `__DATE__` and `__TIME__` which change on every build):

```
package main

/*
#include<stdint.h>
#include<string.h>
void getCompileDateTime(uint8_t  dt[12],uint8_t tm[9]){
  strcpy(dt, __DATE__); //Mmm dd yyyy
  strcpy(tm, __TIME__);  //hh:mm:ss
}
*/
import "C"
import (
    "fmt"
    "unsafe"
)

func main() {
    dt := make([]byte, 12)
    tm := make([]byte, 10)
    C.getCompileDateTime((*C.uint8_t)(unsafe.Pointer(&dt[0])), (*C.uint8_t)(unsafe.Pointer(&tm[0])))
    dts, tms := string(dt), string(tm)
    fmt.Println(dts, tms)
}
```

---

2-

> once cgo is used, the binary will contain $WORK path in the DWARF
>   sections
>   Current problems:
>   1. $WORK path leakage in cgo builds.
>   2. $WORK path leakage in -cover and tests.

ref: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/9206

---

3- 
Building a pure Go program multiple times will generate
identical binaries.

---

I hope this helps.